# SSL on Xampp Localhost using VirtualHost on Windows redirects to Xampp default info/localhost page

Tags: apache, ssl, virtualhost

I have read quite a few postings on configuring SSL on Xampp/Windows/Apache/VirtualHost and think I have done it right, but when I enter in the virtualhost url (q.localhost), I always get to the default localhost Xampp info page, which reads: 'http://q.localhost/xampp/' in the url bar.

Below are what I have in my various files that I think are relevant:

Apache httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

Apache httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<Directory C:/vhost>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#this is the default address of XAMPP    
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/XAMPP/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

#this is the first vhost address in XAMPP
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:/XAMPP/htdocs/data/anycompany"
    ServerName q.localhost
    <Directory "C:/XAMPP/htdocs/data/anycompany">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow   
        Allow from all 
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.key/server.key"
</VirtualHost>

###### THIS WORKS, BUT COMMENTED OUT REPLACED BY THE ABOVE  ########
#this is the first vhost address in XAMPP
#<VirtualHost *:80>
#    DocumentRoot "C:/XAMPP/htdocs/data/anycompany"
#    ServerName q.localhost
#</VirtualHost>
```

Windows Hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       q.localhost
127.0.0.1       test.localhost
```

Apache httpd-ssl.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/data/anycompany"
ServerName q.localhost:443
ServerAdmin admin@localhost.com
```

Apache version 1.8.3 being used.
Doesn't seem to have any error message in the apache error log.

Comment: What do you have in your directory? Move the index.php file to somewhere else which is located in the htdocs folder. And then clear your browser's cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

Seems like the configuration above was correct, but I didn't realize one thing, and I had to include some further configuration to make it work.  Explained below:

1. Typing "q.localhost" in URL window failed, and redirected to the Xampp default page.  Had to include https:// before the url, so typing in "https://q.localhost" brought up the correct page.  However, clicking on the various other links on the website also failed, as it required, but did not have the "https://..." in front of the link.
2. To correct the above problem, I referred to this [article](https://medium.com/@ajtech.mubasheer/setup-https-in-xampp-for-localhost-bc3d01393f31). which suggested adding redirects to configuration file:  \xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf.  I added what he suggested to enable automatic redirects without having to always type in "https://..."

   `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`

   ```
       RewriteEngine On

       # Redirect /xampp folder to https
       RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} xampp
       RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]

       # Redirect /phpMyAdmin folder to https
       RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} phpmyadmin
       RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]

       # Redirect /security folder to https
       RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} security
       RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]

       # Redirect /webalizer folder to https
       RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} webalizer
       RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]

       # Redirect /folder_name folder to https
       RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder_name
       RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]
   ```

   `</IfModule>`